# NSBundle mainBundle returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsbundle

I'm trying to change server settings based on build configurations in Xcode for our iOS app. I am using [this guide](https://cocoacasts.com/switching-environments-with-configurations) as a base. I set up the configuration property in the Info.plist but when I try to get it in code it is coming back `nil`.

[image: info.plist entry]

In searching for solutions and testing I found that I'm getting back `nil` from everything to do with the `mainBundle`. Here is what I've declared in my testing so far. What am I missing/doing wrong?

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *configuration = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"Configuration"];
NSString *bundleName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
NSString *otherName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleNameKey];
```

I'm using Xcode 9.3.

Comment: Here's an obvious question: have you examined the `Info.plist` file in the product bundle to determine if there's a value stored for that key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had duplicated my debug configuration from the release configuration. I noticed that some of the debug properties were not the same. So I deleted and re created the new configurations. This solved the issue. If anyone has any specifics on why the bundle information was not being found in a release build, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

In some instances, for example when your code is executed directly from within Interface Builder, `mainBundle` does not return an object. So, depending on your context you might want to use `bundleForClass:` instead. Specify a class that resides within the bundle you want.

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[YourClass class]];
```

Comment: To be more specific, this can happen when you try to call `[NSBundle mainBundle]` from a different target (e.g. a static library or a Swift module).